# Bootstrap Form Wizard, Validation Error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formwizard

i've implement a plugin called Bootstrap Form Wizard. Is anyone use that?

I'm on going project that use bootstrap and create some form wizard to create transaction. But, the form wizard validation is not working at all.

Here's the syntax i've made to execute the wizard

1. Function Validation

   ```
   function validateText(el) {
   var name = el.val();
   var retValue = {};

   if (name == "") {
       retValue.status = false;
       retValue.msg = "Please enter a name";
   }
   else {
       retValue.status = true;
   }

   return retValue;
   ```

   }
2. My Form Wizard

   ```
       wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: "functions/savetransaction.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: wizard.serialize(),
                   success: function() {
                       wizard.submitSuccess(); // displays the success card
                       wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons
                       wizard.updateProgressBar(0); // sets the progress meter to 0
                       //wizard.reset();
                   },
                   error: function() {
                       wizard.submitError(); // display the error card
                       wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons
                   }
               }); //end ajax wizard
           }); //end submit wizard 

           wizard.on("reset", function(wizard) {
               $.each(wizard.cards, function(name, card) {
                   card.el.find("input").val(""); // resets all inputs on a card to ""
               });
           });

           wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .im-done").click(function() {
               //rest all if clicked
               resetForm();
               wizard.reset().close();
           });

           wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .create-another-trn").click(function() {
               resetForm();
               wizard.reset();
           });
   ```
3. and lastly the HTML

   ```
   <div class="wizard-card" data-cardname="card2">
           <h3>User Accounts</h3>
           <label>User</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder="user" id="add_trc_user" name="user" required="true" maxlength="45" data-validate="validateText"/>
   ```

Is anyone here knows my problem(s) ?

thank you!

Comment: still no comments? is there anyone who use this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce your problem, but the following code works for me (almost all copied from your base code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-wizard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-wizard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wizard" class="wizard">
        <div class="wizard-card" data-cardname="card2">
            <h3>User Accounts</h3>
            <label>User</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="user" id="add_trc_user" name="user" required="true" maxlength="45" data-validate="validateText"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var wizard = $('#wizard').wizard();
        wizard.show();

        wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/savetransaction.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: wizard.serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    wizard.submitSuccess(); // displays the success card
                    wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons
                    wizard.updateProgressBar(0); // sets the progress meter to 0
                    //wizard.reset();
                },
                error: function() {
                    wizard.submitError(); // display the error card
                    wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons
                }
            }); //end ajax wizard
        }); //end submit wizard 

        wizard.on("reset", function(wizard) {
            $.each(wizard.cards, function(name, card) {
                card.el.find("input").val(""); // resets all inputs on a card to ""
            });
        });

        wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .im-done").click(function() {
            //rest all if clicked
            resetForm();
            wizard.reset().close();
        });

        wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .create-another-trn").click(function() {
            resetForm();
            wizard.reset();
        });


    });

 function validateText(el) {
    var name = el.val();
    var retValue = {};

    if (name == "") {
        retValue.status = false;
        retValue.msg = "Please enter a name";
    }
    else {
        retValue.status = true;
    }

    return retValue;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```